# why am I not able to merge hashes within an each loop

Tags: ruby

Iam trying to loop through an array and merge one key/value pair to my hashes within this array, however it is not working. When I do it manually, it is working. What am I doing wrong?

```
:001 > array = [{foo: 5}, {bar: 3}]
 => [{:foo=>5}, {:bar=>3}] 
:002 > array.each{|hash| hash.merge(match: true)}
 => [{:foo=>5}, {:bar=>3}] 
:003 > array[0].merge(match: true)
 => {:foo=>5, :match=>true}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [merge!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) instead of `merge`. `merge` method returns a new hash, `merge!` adds the key value pairs to the hash.

```
array = [{ foo: 5 }, { bar: 3 }]
array.each { |hash| hash.merge!(match: true) }
```

Answer (score 0):

@demir's answer is right.

If you don't want to change the original array. You can use `map` instead of `each` and assign the output to new variable.

```rb
array = [{ foo: 5}, { bar: 3 }]
new_array = array.map { |hsh| hsh.merge(match: true) }
```